# Activity indicator in UITableView in iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iphone app I have a table view.  In that onclick of each row it will download some data.  During that download process I need to animate an activity indicator.  How to add an activity indicator in table view?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add an UIActivityIndicatorView to your view say `activity` Assign it the frame and style you want.

Then all you need to do is that put the below code above your download code.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and you need to declare myMethod as

```
-(void)myMethod:(id)data
{
    [activity startAnimating];
    [activity setHidden:NO];
}
```

Whenever your download finishes just put

```
 [activity stopAnimating];
 [activity setHidden:YES];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanx for ur reply,i tried ur code but am unable to see that indicator,,i think we need to set location(screen co ordinates) of that indicator right?

Comment: Nope you dont necessarily set it dynamically as you have already placed it in XIB and given the co-ordinates there.

Comment: no am not placed in xib,because its a table view am unable to add the activity indicator in interface builder,,,

Comment: @Sowmya: ok then in that case you have to do [[UIActitvityIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:];

Comment: @All: It is better advised to leave a comment while downvoting someone. So that we can improve and learn from our mistakes and do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

First, you do not need to add activity indicator in table view. You just add it in that view and then set its hidden property. When the user clicks on a row, set its hidden property to NO.

One more thing, move your table to send to back from layout->send to back
and the indicator to send to front layout->sent to front.